# Is it necessary to acquire lock for TAILQ_EMPTY() operation

Tags: linux, queue, spinlock

I like to check whether queue is empty or not before accessing the queue. In that case, Is it necessary to acquire lock for TAILQ_EMPTY() operation. Through the definition of TAILQ_EMPTY(), it seems to be reading the queue, so I guess not to use the lock. Am I correct?

**#define        TAILQ_EMPTY(head)                ((head)->tqh_first == NULL)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one process/thread accessing the queue, you don't need to use locks as you don't have any concurrency accesses to the queue.

However, if you have multiple processes/threads accessing the queue inserting and removing elements in a concurrent manner, then you need to protect these accesses using locks.

For instance, imagine the case where you test if the queue is empty but some other process/thread is inserting an element in the queue at the same time. If you don't write your code taking into account such situations then your code will behave non-deterministically.

Reading the code of `sys/queue.h` shows that there are no protection from concurrent accesses so you have to handle them yourself if you have concurrent code.